# Is this version of Implicit Function Theorem correct?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, banach-spaces, implicit-function-theorem

I have come across this variant of the implicit function theorem in the book ["Topics in Nonlinear Functional Analysis" by Ralph A. Artino](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Topics_in_Nonlinear_Functional_Analysis.html?id=zFMkcgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y).

---

**Theorem 2.7.2 (Implicit Function Theorem)** Let $X, Y$, and $Z$ be Banach spaces and $f$ a continuous mapping of an open set $U \subset X \times Y \rightarrow Z$. Assume that $f$ has a Frechet derivative with respect to $x, f_x(x, y)$, which is continuous in $U$. Let $\left(x_0, y_0\right) \in U$ and $f\left(x_0, y_0\right)=0$. If $A=f_x\left(x_0, y_0\right)$ is an isomorphism of $X$ onto $Z$ then:

- (i) There is a ball $\left\{y:\left\|y-y_0\right\|<r\right\}=B_r\left(y_0\right)$ and a unique continuous map $u: B_r\left(y_0\right) \rightarrow X$ such that $u\left(y_0\right)=x_0$ and $f(u(y), y) \equiv 0$.
- (ii) If $f$ is of class $C^1$, then $u(y)$ is of class $C^1$ and
  $$
  u_y(y)=-\left[f_x(u(y), y)\right]^{-1} \circ f_y(u(y), y) .
  $$
- (iii) $u_y(y)$ belongs to $C^p$ if $f$ is in $C^p, p>1$.

---

My main interest is in part (i), which I need for a proof. What confuses me, and I wanted to check, was that this version of the Implicit Function Theorem seems to require no differentiability of $f$ with respect to $y$... is this correct?! I cannot find another version with such relaxed conditions anywhere. It seems the theorem always usually requires differentiability on both $x$ and $y$, no?

---

Update: The book cites another paper found [here](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272601/1-s2.0-S0022123600X04107/1-s2.0-0022123671900152/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEBAaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQCYR8VCCSBHTAiDRWXkWKXX6K%2Bi9YTnE8jEJbvyBnh5QQIgIr%2FYxcuOca%2F6EQH0MkmH1GxB1t%2FEcJmUJnUKU3ecLQQqswUISBAFGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDNzpPSxgMtdfvc%2B%2FnSqQBXPldIUjMq0KoZu0mtvgpT0wD08V%2FROARPd35nrJGZ5qgklIbfZPrbfVkFO2Me250G5hI2G1Gpa0ZEvIQjpWfXPoemhN%2Bprtx2KdeEMnKg%2BDoleUidIw%2BaxUBumMmg25T%2FcD8i1Cm3laZnwKbuf50rTNWfWRLFm7cWxE8inAzeotJASvBZBPF1u38%2BZ1AQqQvcBqxOZGoDGdTtfGbF0F7wJ6ZEnCb%2FGEGzkrF1ZHpQ0REIVPk5DuDCeZ4qqBeRs3KxUCoCxERe2%2Fr42fNCn3zv0UTgcDpAs%2BRSOyyJUFxGrNRf96hzDewooDqnmDbWOq5c%2F6cHobI3dx8WcWiZn2S6nsSPkIRzAwxmIiJ9Ru6WyHjZ1Zj70GQNUi8illR8qPFy4srIjQ6qVQuPfWLP57l30IDOy2%2BAhCc5uY2caIHUxFghVNZCGESwU2m9781G93g1EYYoN7x07EHvMIl7YN50qDuaU05HQ76uB5cnspYF5zi7yJugnBW3kWDuNdKVWUS8Axudhig%2BV0tUPXLJ79KXuYUp0KMoEm0AimdNI71g3r%2BVm7sG0vvauOkkkYYcB2I4j1Ya%2B4pirYSfDdz%2FyRCdKLsJewo3V3uMZHN8wVsNFSPZODrBhWTp9a9wLp2%2FaTO%2ByF8DxO0CLaWmKQAremGLvbuHi2LGXmhRvXdW1X56vk6ocrI1Ji9Fyq7UptUs1qMbdmlNaBB4uSM9O0y4tvXHMKRXpAhjirK7pz5uTJ0Ee48sDURQtk26IO6wImzOUTxrNq9vlntgxwnQ5XeD%2BFsrbPG%2BeWoGqv6VxpdP6JZ%2FV4yJ0YpG2UUH4D3zZOMa1QiDyq%2Br6EzDyIOTPLOqJw3elonUgYU8H0eEreGGvb%2FgeZMKWZlKoGOrEBMoLpBuBPKjYcHpDJmQT%2BATdDlvabWMehRqXk9JExW4pnRxVJixKyUUMOwJ8MlzQfcwVG2WoJXQT4yBJ1tzNoEL1liQCTy%2FU7FQS3%2B%2BBrNr%2BjY%2F7lddqSP7LueSWXYF9jNwVpI7r5ZEOy7JV0htruuaUGkbUcRr8z%2BQE%2BZc25jo0vorGWSB9z4ajO9y1BrmBhG6L4YNtOtWefW%2BZ1cuJei8VC9hQxTxJdrahLnaFh%2FHAQ&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20231103T153040Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYQL5MERFE%2F20231103%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=0c8e26af2b1ea06855f74a5ba67f277432aa0090dc11e76306fade9c44f6cbac&hash=fa5346be6813ad211bac8832af41d721f784cf01e749a7f1f0982f6a5ad9976d&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0022123671900152&tid=spdf-1128857f-2bbb-4533-ab54-7ef5fefd24a4&sid=ec750e8167537742bd0b8802e8d83710abecgxrqb&type=client&tsoh=d3d3LnNjaWVuY2VkaXJlY3QuY29t&ua=1d045c575650065801590a&rr=8205a8e9de074197&cc=gb) as a reference for the implicit function theorem but this paper does not prove it and instead states:

> This theorem is certainly well-known, but we did not find a convenient reference for the precise statement we have used.

---

Another update: I found the version of the proof I was looking for [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-19670-7_14) ([pdf link](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-030-19670-7_14.pdf)).

Comment: did they provide a proof? While I can’t immediately confirm, I guess this is plausible? You could try to run the usual iteration procedure to find a fixed point and apply Banach’s theorem (of course, one cannot deduce (i) as a corollary of the usual inverse function theorem).

Comment: I couldn't fit my response in the comments so I updated the question text. Long story short; they reference to someone else who claims it without proof or citation, and even make a point of saying so. I'm not familiar with the iteration procedure you mention - does it prove the result in this case?

Comment: Actually, check Loomis and Sternberg, section 4.9, Theorem 9.3.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but doesn't that require differentiability with respect to both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in their notation? ($x$ and $y$ in the notation of the question above)

Comment: Ah I've found it now! Added a link to the question.

Comment: no, their notation $dG^2_{(\alpha,\beta)}$ might be non-standard now, but they mean that the partial derivative $\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}$ is continuous and at each point $(x,y)$ is an isomorphism $Y\to Z$ (so ok apart from swapping the roles of $X,Y$, it is the same assumption as given here). So, they are saying that if the partial derivative is continuous and at a point invertible, then locally we have a continuous implicit function. In the next theorem, they upgrade regularity.